# Sort files by modification date, then by name

Tags: shell, ls

Let us assume a directory that contains pictures from different cameras:

```
DCIM1234.JPG
DCIM1235.JPG
DCIM1236.JPG

DSCN4120.JPG
DSCN4121.JPG
DSCN4122.JPG
DSCN4123.JPG

IMG5840.JPG
IMG5841.JPG
IMG5842.JPG
IMG5843.JPG
```

Sorting all these files by modification date across cameras is easy using `ls -t`. The problem is that most file systems have an accuracy of 1 second or more, so some pictures might have an identical timestamps, for instance when shooting bursts. In this case, `ls -t` might loose the natural order of the file, which is reflected in the names.

How to sort the files by modification time, while sorting by name the files that have an identical modification time?

Comment: Perhaps something as simple as stat -c "%Y %n" * | sort -gk1,1r -gk2,2`? Assumes no special characters in the file names, doesn't find hidden files, etc.

Comment: ... or perhaps (since no specific shell is tagged) zsh with the `Om` and `on` glob qualifiers ex. `zsh -c 'print -rC1 *.JPG(NOmon)'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, it's recommended to avoid parsing `ls` output.  As doneal24 suggested above, `stat` is a better option.

```
$ stat -c "%Y/%n" *.JPG | sort -t/ -k1,1n -k2 | sed 's@^.*/@@'
```

From `man stat`:

> The valid format sequences for files (without --file-system):
> ...
> %n     file name
> %Y     time of last data modification, seconds since Epoch

So `stat -c "%Y/%n" *.JPG` will get you the timestamp in seconds and the name of each file, separated by a `/`.  For example:

```
1580845717/IMG5841.JPG
```

The output of that command is piped to `sort -t/ -k1,1n -k2`, which sorts first by the first column, numerically (the timestamp), and then by the second column.  Columns are separated by `/` (`-t/`).

Finally, the output of the `sort` command is piped to `sed`, which removes all character up to and including the first `/` (the chosen delimiter).  The result in the list of filenames in the order you wanted (with the "newest" files listed last).

Comment: Better than my answer, nice job!

Comment: That sounds good. A more generic solution would be:
`find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 stat -c "%Y/%n" | sort -t/ -k1,1n -k2 | sed 's@^.*/@@'`

Answer (score 0):

Look into the command `sort` combined with formatting the `ls` date output. Something like this should be a good starting point:

```bsh
TIME_STYLE=+%s ls -l | sort -k6,6n -k7 | awk '{print $7}'
```

Based on the output of `ls -l` like this:

```bsh
-rw-rw-r--. 1 ajc ajc  669 1626129161 commit-types.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 ajc ajc 3578 1638037524 emacsintro.org
-rw-r--r--  1 ajc ajc  170 1646399639 README.md
```

Explanation of each part of that command:

1. TIME_STYLE formats the date column of `ls -l`. In this case, we're using the Unix epoch style of output with `+%s`
2. `sort -k6,6n -k7`. Sort numerically on the 6th column of `ls -l` output, then sort by the 7th column using the default method which is alphabetical.
3. `awk '{print $7}'`. Just shows the 7th column. If you wanted to show the 6th column, you'd need to use `awk '{print $6 $7}'` instead.

Here's the [sort documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/sort-invocation.html#sort-invocation) and the [file timestamp documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html).